# Access an array in a separate file?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I'm working on learning Python. I'm building a hangman app, and I have the user select the amount of letters in a word.

I'd have an array called `Three`, `Four`, `Five`, etc with the corresponding length of words in those arrays. I want to make each of the arrays their own file, so the main script isn't so cumbersome.

I then want to be able to use `random.randint` to select one of the words from one of the arrays after the user indicates the amount of letters they want. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Please elaborate on exactly what you mean by **I want to make each of the arrays their own file**. What is the original source of these lists? What have you tried so far?

Comment: For example, there would be a file called three.py that would simply contain an array of three-lettered words. four.py would have four letter words and so on. I can't try much because I simply don't know the command for python to access another python file, which is why I came here.

Comment: You can store your lists in another `.py` file and import them into your hangman script, you do not need to open any file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, make sure all of your python file are in the same folder.

Once you have done this, you can simple do `from name_of_word_file import name_of_word_list`

You could make one of these lines for every file, but I think it would be easier to simply put all of your word lists into one file, and then import the specific word list variables.

As for selecting a word from the list, random.choice can randomly select and element from a list like so

```
from random import choice
from words import four_letter_words

print choice(four_letter_words)
```

Using lists and importing them will work just fine, but I suggest you look into saving things like word lists to text file like what Ken mentions in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

To access files, you want the `open` command.

For example, to open a file for *read* named *three.dat*, you would do:

```
with open("three.dat") as f:
    # do stuff
```

The `with` there sets the scope of the file handle such that you don't need to explicitly close it. When `f` goes out of scope, the file will automatically close.

More info on `open`:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

If you just have a relatively small number of words, say a dozen or so, that fit into each bucket, it may be best/most feasible to simply hardcode them into a `dict` of `list`s, where the key is the length converted to a string.

i.e. something of the form:

```
word_dict = {'3': ['and', 'cat', 'dog', 'not'],
             '4': ['four', 'moth'],
             '5': ['batch', 'match']
            }
```

However, if you want to have, say, a whole dictionary's worth of words, then a hardcoding approach would not be feasible (although getting those into separate files would also be tedious).

Ultimately, as you progress in your learning of *Python*, you may want to look into something like this and adapt it into your program:

http://wordlist.aspell.net/

Comment: I think the OP is on about a module to store some variables that can be imported, not actually in a file.

Comment: Ah. So perhaps @David Greydanus's answer is more what he's looking for. Still seems like all the caveats I listed would apply, though (seems like it would still be quite tedious marshalling up the contents of whatever's imported using that approach).

Comment: This looks like a good way to do it too. Maybe a combination of both David's answer and this. Using one object with multiple parameters as the word length storage would work. I just want the separate file because I'm using a lot of words, so having all of them in the same file would just take up a lot of space. Thanks!